# AWS Codebuild Download source point to repo 1 but should be repo 2

Tags: github-actions, aws-codebuild, github-actions-reusable-workflows

i have 2 repository
node.mobile-qa-automation with no codebuild
python.settlement-qa-automation with buildspec.yml

when i trigger the repository python with a workflow_call from node, the source of the codebuild included on python repo points node how can i change it?

```
*****STARTING CODEBUILD*****
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:20:50.033473 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:20:50.235005 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:21:01.805528 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:21:01.809426 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src4097766002/src/github.com/xxx/node.mobile-qa-automation
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:21:01.813942 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/01/17 19:21:01.813959 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/src4097766002/src/github.com/xxx/node.mobile-qa-automation/codebuild/settlement-qa-automation/buildspec.yml: no such file or directory
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
Error: Build status: FAILED
*****CODEBUILD COMPLETE*****
```